# CakePHP 2.x display map location using address?

Tags: cakephp, google-maps-api-3, cakephp-2.0

I have CakePHP website I want to display Google map and marker in given address on my CakePHP  application.

Is there any plugin available to display address in Google map.

Comment: You can use Cake helper, but the primary of problem is JavaScript, check Google Developers site with examples

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not even try to google.
Or you would have stumpled upon at least a dozen plugins/solutions.

Check this one out:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/12/21/googlemapsv3-cakephp-helper/

```
// include jquery js
$this->Html->script('jquery', array('inline' => false));

// include the google js code
$this->Html->script($this->GoogleMapV3->apiUrl(), array('inline' => false));

// echo the div container to display the map in
echo $this->GoogleMapV3->map(array('div'=>array('height'=>'400', 'width'=>'100%')));

$options = array(
    'lat' => 48.95145,
    'lng' => 11.6981,
    'title' => 'Some title', // optional
    'content' => '<b>HTML</b> Content for the Bubble/InfoWindow' // optional
);
$this->GoogleMapV3->addMarker($options);

// finalize js
$this->GoogleMapV3->finalize();
// Make sure you got `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('inline' => true));` somewhere in your layout then
```

If you do not have the lat/lng yet, you can either geocode via JS at runtime or use Cake to do so: http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/06/12/geocoding-with-cakephp/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper](https://github.com/marcferna/CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper) that will geocode the address on the fly and add it to your map. You would do something like this: (see more details on the link shared)

```php
<?= $this->GoogleMap->addMarker("map_canvas", 1, "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, California"); ?>
```